# Create same access token for multiple devices

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, owin, katana

I am using the katana owin project in my Web Api 2 project.
I want that user will be able to login from different devices,
for example: smartphone and tablet.
And that the user will get the same token if its not yet passed.
In the current situation, if the user is login from his smartphone he will get one token and refresh token, and then if he login from his tablet he will get another token and a new refresh token.
How can I solved this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the user to have the same token on each device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out, the different token is not the problem, the server accept both.
I just need that the refresh token will be the same as long that he valid.
So now in my refresh token creation I return the same refresh token, and extend is expires date. 
After do that all works!